# How do make binary Search in list of structures in C#?

Tags: c#, list, search, structure, binary-search

I want to ask how can I implement binary search in a List where I have 50,000 structures.

I sort this list by **word** like this **listSub.OrderBy(s => s.word);**

```
public struct SubItem
{
    public string word;
    public int count;

    public SubItem(string word, int count)
    {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

I dont know how binary search in **List**<**SubItem**>. Can you help me?

Comment: This looks like a homework - please show some research. Here's a hint, though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search

Comment: A better way would be to use a `word => count` hash-map, than a list of `word, count` pairs ordered by key.

Comment: `List` already has a `BinarySearch` method.  You call that method.  It returns the index of the item.  You're done.

Comment: I have Dictionary<int, List<SubItem>>. The number represent the number of document. The List<subItem> represent the stem word and number his occurrence in this document. The c# havent hashtable. Do you think that is better to use inner dictionary?

Comment: When I want to find subItem where word is equal to some word. I have to go through the whole list and compare word with a search word and then stop the cycle. This is challenging if I have subitems 2000.

Answer (score 0):

The key to a binary search is that all of the items to the left of the center item are less than the center item, and to the right are all greater. The other key is that any given section of the list behaves as a sorted list in its own right, and thus that property still applies. So you keep breaking the list in half until you have found your element. This is usually done with recursion, with an empty list as the base case that the element does not exist in the list.

Here is some pseudocode to get you started:

```
find (list, start, end, target) {
     if (start > end)  // this is called a base case, look into recursion
        return -1

     center = (end - start) / 2

     if list[center] == target    // this is also a base case
          return center;

     else if list[center] > target
          return find(list, start, center-1, target)

     else 
          return find(list, center+1, end, target)

}
```

And we would run it like so:

```
list = [ 1 , 3, 7, 9, 12, 15, 17, 21, 28 ]
// need to find the target in the list
find(list, 0, list.length - 1, 3);
```

this would first look at 12, which is bigger than our target, so then it would split the list in half, look at the middle of the lesser half which is 3 and find it, returning its index. It tends to be more beneficial on larger and larger lists.

I said it uses recursion, which means two things: it will call itself until it finds an answer, and that when it finds the answer, it stops calling itself. There are two main kinds of recursion which you might find out about later, but the most important parts are those two: the recursive step (calling itself) and the base case (when it stops calling itself). Without those two parts something is not recursive.

Comment: I understand.Thanks so much, but when I have string instead of integer? I compare two string but how can I say that is on left or rigth site array?

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList. It has a method named as BinarySearch.